# Why don't I get an error when adding a duplicate item to a Set?

Tags: java, set

I added the same integer twice to a `Set`, but it will not give any error despite `Set`s not allowing duplicates. Why is this?

```
 Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
 set.add(1);
 set.add(1);
```

Comment: It is not supposed to give you a error when you try to add duplicates in set. That's how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 9):

`Set:add` is not supposed to give you an error when you try to add a value already in the `Set`. It will just return `false` and not add the value to the `Set`.

Check the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-):

> boolean add(E e)
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 3):

[Set.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) returns a boolean. If the item is already in the set, the return value is false.

So if you have a choice. Either...

```
if (!set.add(i)) {
    // item already in set; not added
}
```

... or

```
if (set.contains(i)) {
    // item already in set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the official JAVA doc for more information about add method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29

It will simply return false if the Set already contains the element.